# How to strip spaces in Python and UNIX to render only one space uniformly throughout the string

Tags: python, unix

Assume my string is

```
a = '    Hello, I  am     trying  to       strip spaces  perfectly '
```

I know that:

- Stripping using `a.strip()` will remove preceding and leading spaces.
- Using `a.replace(" ","")` I can remove one space etc

How to formulate this so that no matter how many spaces there are the output will always be rendered as only **one space** between each word and none at the start or end?

(in python and Unix) ... thanks!

Comment: Obviously, the Python part has a duplicate.  However, the unix part is off-topic, and belongs on unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) then [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). Using `str.split` will automatically get rid of extra whitespace:

```
>>> a = '    Hello, I  am     trying  to       strip spaces  perfectly '
>>> print ' '.join(a.split())
Hello, I am trying to strip spaces perfectly
```

Using shell tools (thank you [AdamKG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16361/adamkg)!) :

```
$ echo '    Hello, I  am\n     trying  to       strip spaces  perfectly ' | tr -s "[:space:]" " " | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//'
Hello, I am trying to strip spaces perfectly
```

Comment: This is a particularly nice way to do it, because it handles all white space including tabs and newlines, not just spaces.

Comment: Thanks! Waiting on the UNIX solution to this

Comment: `echo '    Hello, I  am     trying  to       strip spaces  perfectly ' | tr -s "[:space:]" " " | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//'` output: `Hello, I am trying to strip spaces perfectly`

Comment: well dammit, ate my extra spaces. Will edit the answer and include in a block.

Comment: Could you please explain the second pipe Adam? thanks

Comment: @AdamKG Hey adam, I much appreciate the edit. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @LP the tr step just collapses sequences of whitespace into a single space, the 2nd pipe (sed) strips the leftover leading/trailing space.

Comment: You can use `sed` for all the processing if you are going to use it at all. `sed 's/  */ /g;s/^ //;s/ $//' <<<'    Hello,   I    am   trying    to    strip spaces     perfectly    ' `

Comment: Nice! And TIL about ';' to chain sed commands, I've been using multiple -e args.